# How to make Final Cut Pro to use my Tera bytes' HDD and not my Laptop's HDD?

Tags: video, final-cut-pro

I want all videos to my external HDD and not my laptop's HDD and Final Cut Pro does not give this option. I am not wanting to use my MBA's free space for video editing. How can I define the location of videos in Final Cut Pro?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Change the Save to location to be your external drive.**

Since 10.1 you can also create a library which can be stored externally. See:

- http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5958

Comment: I see it is that easy -- just create a new library and move that to the new HDD -- and how do you move a project from one library to another library?

Comment: @hhh Just drag it inside FCPX

Comment: Can you clarify how to drag it inside FCPX?

Comment: @hhh Have both libraries open, find the project in the library and drag it from the browser to the other project.